# defining diagonals in python

Tags: python, numpy, diagonal

How would I go about creating the matrix

```
[[ 1  2  0  0  0]
 [-1  1  2  0  0]
 [ 0 -1  1  2  0]
 [ 0  0 -1  1  2]
 [ 0  0  0 -1  1]]
```

using the `numpy.diag()` function in Python?

I want to define the main diagonal and also the parallel diagonals of the matrix.

Comment: matrix like this

[1  2  0  0  0;
-1  1  2  0  0;
 0 -1  1  2  0;
 0  0 -1  1  2;
 0  0  0 -1  1]

Comment: What 'matrix' type?  That's not valid input or display for any common type.

Comment: `scipy.sparse` has `diag` that let you specify several diagonals at once, but the `numpy` version(s) only does one at a time. But array addition is fast.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
import numpy as np

subdiagonal = np.diag([-1,-1,-1,-1], -1)
diagonal = np.diag([1,1,1,1,1])
superdiagonal = np.diag([2,2,2,2], 1)

total = subdiagonal + diagonal + superdiagonal

print(total)
```

It gives this output:

```
[[ 1  2  0  0  0]
 [-1  1  2  0  0]
 [ 0 -1  1  2  0]
 [ 0  0 -1  1  2]
 [ 0  0  0 -1  1]]
```